# How to hide mat-sidnav scrollbar in angular material?

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material

How can you hide the scrollbar in angular material mat-sidenav, I tried adding `overflow: hidden` to the sidenav but doesn't seem to work.

`Markup:`

```html
  <mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container" [style.marginTop.px]="mobileQuery.matches ? 56 : 0">
    <mat-sidenav #snav [opened]="(sidebar$|async)===true" [mode]="mobileQuery.matches ? 'over' : 'side'"
      [fixedInViewport]="mobileQuery.matches" fixedTopGap="56">
      <mat-nav-list>
        <mat-list-item routerLink="." *ngFor="let nav of fillerNav">
          <mat-icon mat-list-icon>home</mat-icon>
          <div mat-line *ngIf="!isCompact"> {{nav}}</div>
        </mat-list-item>
      </mat-nav-list>
    </mat-sidenav>

    <mat-sidenav-content>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
```

`SCSS:`

```css
.sidenav-container {
  flex: 1;
  &.mat-nav-list {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

`Screenshot:`

[image: Screenshot of the compact sidebar]

Answer (score 1):

Try to assign these two classes the the list: "invisible-scroll m-list"

```
.invisible-scroll {
   -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
   scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}
.invisible-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
   display: none;
}


.m-list{
  flex-grow: 1;  
  overflow: auto;
}
```

I tested with mat-list and it works well. Not sure about the mat-nav-list

Comment: Assgning the classes `<mat-nav-list class="invisible-scroll m-list">` still shows the scrollbar.  Tried it with the mat-list as well.